# What class/control is used when you place a Picture in a MSVC++ dialog template?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, winapi

I've not been able to find this out, which seems weird. When I add a class variable for the control using the wizard, it wants to add a CButton. Is there a specific control or does one of the basic ones provide this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an icon or a bitmap in your dialog, you usually want to use a `CStatic` control.
A CStatic can either display an HICON or an HBITMAP, see [CStatic::SetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b7w5x74z(VS.80).aspx) and [CStatic::SetIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5w91yh47(v=VS.80).aspx).
It's also possible to directly choose an icon or image resource for the control in the dialog editor.